# SQL with unknown purpose

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have to change some SQL queries (SQL Server 2005) done by another person and in that code I see often the following construction:

```
SELECT fieldA, SUM(CASE fieldB  WHEN null THEN 0  ELSE fieldB END) as AliasName FROM ...
```

I don't understand the case statement because as far as I know, null can not be checked within a case and therefore I think that the above code does the same as:

```
SELECT fieldA, SUM(fieldB) as AliasName FROM ...
```

I have also done some tests and have not seen any differences in the result. Am I missing something, or can I replace the upper statement through the short one?

**UPDATE**

Only for completeness because it's not mentioned in the answers: *The upper code returns the same result as the lower*. The used `case` construction does not replace null's through zero's and therefore it can be ommited. If the purpose of the original sql was to make sure that never null will be returned, the `coalesce` or the `isnull`-operator can be used (as stated in the answers).

Comment: Maybe they just dont know COALESCE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of your second statement will contain `nulls` (when aggregating records that *only* have `null` values for `fieldB`). If you don't mind that, you're ok.

If you want zeros in your output rather than `null` values, use this:

```
select fieldA, sum(isnull(fieldB, 0)) as AliasName from ...
```

Comment: How will he get `NULL` in the `SUM`?

Comment: When there are no non-null values being aggregated, it outputs null.

Comment: +1 Deleted my post and upvoted yours as you're mentionning about the null values in the result set, and how to remove them from it.

Comment: @Jeff Sternal, and does it perform equal to `isnull(sum(filedB,0))` in sql server 2005?

Comment: typo - supposed to be `isnull(sum(fieldB),0)`

Comment: @Unreason - no idea: perhaps you should post another question.

Comment: not really interested :D just wanted to suggest that if unsure you would want to use isnull(sum(fieldB),0) because sum(filedB) might take advantage of an index in some cases (mostly if there's no where condition)

Answer (score 1):

You would achieve this more readably with

```
SELECT fieldA, COALESCE(fieldB, 0) as AliasName
```

Comment: You mean SUM(COALESCE(fieldB,0)) as AliasName, right? Is this more efficient than sum(isnull(fieldB, 0)) as it is posted by JeffSternal?

Comment: Yes, of course, sorry. I have no idea if it's more efficient, more a question of style